# DropDown menu with ClickEvent

Tags: html, jquery-ui, css, drop-down-menu

When I click a button, then a drop down menu must be shown. When I click anywhere in the page it, needs to hide. The problem I have is here: when I run the page, I can see the drop down menu instead of the click event. I tried with different `div` tags, but to no effect.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Navya/69KGD/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your dropdown list visibility to false (to hide it) when page loads.

```
$("#container").hide();
```

After that, when you click the button you set visibility to true (show it).

```
$("#container").show();
```

Comment: You didnt understand properly, when i click on  img button then a drop down menu must appear, when i click on page it need to hide, now in both panels

Comment: <div class="button dropmenu">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown"><img src="../images/Forward.JPG"></a>
                     <ul class="menucontainer" style="margin:0px">
                            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>

Comment: But hear, when ever we drag each panel then drop down menu is displaying or when we load or run again for fraction of seconds we can view dropdown menu.

Comment: I tried with you code to upgrade in this way, but still there is problem hear, couldnt able to find where issue is. when we load the page i can see drop down menu "blink" and when  we click o n drop down menu half part is getting disaled due to 2 panel http://jsfiddle.net/Navya/69KGD/15/

Comment: HI Thank you, i tried implementing the Functionality which you have said in my page but still i cant able to find Dropdown menu with click event, i copied the same code exactly, but still went wrong in my page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975994/dropdown-menu-using-jquery

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975994/dropdown-menu-using-jquery you have forgotten to put $("h1").click(function(){return false;}); The last link is http://jsfiddle.net/69KGD/22/