# DropDown Menu Using Jquery

Tags: css, html, jquery-ui

I got this issue, In the above html I cannot click on the dropdown menu, I went wrong some where ,my dropdown menu in this code is not working can any one please let me know where i went wrong? 
    
    
CSS:

Javascript:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.menucontainer').hide();
    $('#container').sortable({
        handle:'h1',
        scroll: false,
        revert: true,
        tolerance: 'pointer'
    });


    $('.dropmenu').on('click', function(){
        var $ul = $('.menucontainer', this);            
        $ul.show(500);
        console.log( $ul );
        return false;
    });

    $('html').on('click', function() {
        $('.menucontainer').hide(500);
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: try it on http://jsfiddle.net/bvVEb/ see if it works if not please provide information about what should be different

Comment: Would it be possible to create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your code?

Comment: Hi, When we click on image a drop down menu must be visible, when i click anywhere in page it need to be disappear,i tried solving it , but in my page it is not working

Comment: Define "not working", please. Describe what is wrong. Looks ok to me: http://jsfiddle.net/Exceeder/ZBUP6/

Comment: The same code in Fiddle i can see DropDown Menu when i click, but when i copy the same code in my page drag and drop is working fine in this, but when i click a drop down menu i cant able to see dropdown menu, i am using jquert plugins jquery-1.3.2.min.js and jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js, please can any let me know where i went wrong i am very new face for jquery, struggling for this functionality from past week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a number of issues in your code.  I think I've fixed them all here: http://jsfiddle.net/exuY9/

A couple of things:

1. In your last bit of JS, you have an event handler inside of another event handler.  While this is legal, I doubt it what you intended;
2. Your code may have actually been working in that I think it was showing the menus as you wanted, but it was also immediately hiding them as well.  Why? Because your onclick handler for the #dr1, #dr2 were allowing the click to continue through the page onto the HTML's onclick handler, which immediately undid the show() again so fast, you thought nothing was happening at all;
3. I've also moved all of your code to inside the $(function(){...}); block, only because I wasn't sure of you were inserting this code in your `head`, in which case, the elements wouldn't be present to attach handlers, to.  If your script was attached at the end of the `body` then this would be less of a concern;
4. Instead of creating a new handler for each ID of the same class, you can just make one for the class.  You can see how I've done this a couple of times in the revised code;
5. And, as a matter of style, it has become customary amongst front-end devs, to use single quotes in Javascript and double-quotes in HTML.  This will save you a lot of headaches as if you use double quotes in both, you'll end up needing to escape stuff all the time.

Comment: Hi mkoistine, I want the same functionality what u have given in fiddle, but it is not working in my web page

Comment: I am Using the above plugins <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js">

Comment: Ah, well, you'll need to either update your jQuery (yours is quite old) or you'll need to convert the event handlers back to the older, click style.  Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/exuY9/1/.  Also, you probably have a 'click' handler on your `.draggable`s that is eating up your clicks.  Hard to say with what you've posted here.

Comment: I would just like to say that you're making your life a bit difficult by having these "menus" inside a draggable.  This isn't impossible to make work by any stretch, but it will require a deeper understanding of events than you have shown here so far.  I've always found this to be a good starting point: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: Thank you mkoistinen, i will go through the above link for a good starting in events